# How to create a folder on WebMatrix

Tags: iis-7, directory, razor, virtual-directory, webmatrix

How do I create a sub folder within the Pictures folder?

I need this because when you save a project, will create a folder where the folder name is the project code, and then I will save the images in this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Click the Files Workspace (in the Left Panel)
2) Select the parent folder (or root of the site) in the Tree
3) In the Ribbon, in the "New" Button, click only the Arrow (the bottom of the button) and you will see a "New Folder" option. Note that if you click the center of the button you will get the "new file dialog" so you need to click only the arrow facing downwards.

Comment: I would like to create a folder via code. Once you create a new project is created a folder for that project in IIS.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to use System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(), and more specifically you could use Server.MapPath as well to get the physical directory. So say you want to create a folder "Images" under the root of the app, you can use System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/images"); ...  the ~ character will give you the root of the application.